# HTML page reloading without updating text areas' data

Tags: javascript, html

In my [HTML page](http://plnkr.co/edit/UxcMxzwVShuMjEAo2wug?p=preview) there are two Text Areas with default values and a SUBMIT button.

After SUBMIT has been pressed by the user, I want to update the two text areas with the new numbers, and at the same time use the values to call the function `loadCountryDataFromCsv(countrySelected, indicatorSelected)`.

The problem is that the whole page is reloading, ignoring the values inserted by the user and using the ones inserted by default in the HTML body.

```
    <html>              

     <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>Homicide count and rate</title>

      <script type="text/javascript" src="d3.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        google.load("visualization", "1", {
          packages: ["corechart"]
        });
        google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

        function drawChart() {
          var range = loadRange();

          function loadCountryDataFromCsv(countrySelected, indicatorSelected){

                 //loadData from CSV and drawChart();
          }

          function loadRange(){
              var minCnt = document.getElementById('minCnt').value;
              var maxCnt = document.getElementById('maxCnt').value;
              var range = new Array();
              range[0] = minCnt;
              range[1] = maxCnt;
              // var minRt = document.getElementById('minRt');
              // var maxRt = document.getElementById('maxRt');
              return range;
          }

          var submit = document.getElementById('submit');
          submit.onchange = function(){
            // alert(";;;min;;;"+ minCnt+'\n:::max;;;'+maxCnt);
            var minCnt = document.getElementById('minCnt').value;
            var maxCnt = document.getElementById('maxCnt').value;

            range[0] = minCnt; range[1] = maxCnt;

            var countrySelected = document.getElementById('country-select').value;
            var indicatorSelected = document.getElementById('data-select').value;

            // alert(";;;min;;;"+ minCnt+'\n:::max;;;'+maxCnt
            //+"\ncountrySelected "+ countrySelected + '\nindicatorSelected ' + indicatorSelected);
            loadCountryDataFromCsv(countrySelected, indicatorSelected);
          }
        }
      </script>
   </head>





      <body>
        <div style="margin-left: 5px; width: 100%;">
           <d1 style="float: left;"><big>Intentional homicide, counts and rates per 100,000 population</big></d1> <br><br>
           <d1 style="float: left;">Intentional homicide is defined as unlawful death inflicted upon a person with the intent to cause death or serious injury.</d1> <br><br>
        </div>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Select a Country</legend>
            <d1>Region: &nbsp; </d1>
            <select id="region-select">
                <option value="Africa">Africa</option>
                <option value="Americas" selected>Americas</option>
                <option value="Asia">Asia</option>
                <option value="Europe">Europe</option>
                <option value="Oceania">Oceania</option>
            </select>
            <d1>&nbsp;&nbsp;Subregion: &nbsp; </d1>
            <select id="subregion-select">
                <!-- <option value="" selected>none</option> -->
            </select>
            <d1>&nbsp;&nbsp;Country: &nbsp; </d1>
            <select id="country-select">
            </select><br><br>
            <d1>Indicator Select: &nbsp; </d1>
            <select id="data-select">
                <option value="count" selected>count</option>
                <option value="rate">rate</option>
            </select>
            <d1>&nbsp;&nbsp;Format Select: &nbsp; </d1>
            <select id="format-select">
                <option value="">none</option>
                <option value="decimal" selected>decimal</option>
                <option value="scientific">scientific</option>
                <!-- <option value="percent">percent</option>
                <option value="currency">currency</option> -->
                <option value="short">short</option>
                <option value="long">long</option>
            </select>

            <form><br> 
                <d1>Min Range:  &nbsp; </d1> 
                 <input style="width: 55px;" id="minCnt" type="text" name="minCnt" value="0">  &nbsp;&nbsp;
                <d1>Max Range:  &nbsp; </d1> 
                 <input style="width: 55px;" id="maxCnt" type="text" name="maxCnt" value="10000">
                   &nbsp;&nbsp; <input onclick="return updateRange();" id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" onsubmit="return false;">
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    function updateRange(){
                        var minCnt = document.getElementById('minCnt').value;
                        var maxCnt = document.getElementById('maxCnt').value;

                        var countrySelected = document.getElementById('country-select').value;
                        var indicatorSelected = document.getElementById('data-select').value;

                        loadCountryDataFromCsv(countrySelected, indicatorSelected);                    

                        return false;

                        // var minBox = document.getElementById("minCnt").value;
                        // var maxBox = document.getElementById("maxCnt").value;
                        // minBox.value = "new value";
                        // maxBox.value = "new value";                      
                        // console.log(";;;");                    
                    }            
                </script> 

            </form>
        </fieldset>
        <div id="chart_div" style="margin-left: -90px; width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Pluckr code -> http://plnkr.co/edit/UxcMxzwVShuMjEAo2wug?p=preview

In order to stop reloading the page, I've already tried using

`<input onclick="return false;" id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" onsubmit="return false;">`

but the problem is that while the page is not loading, at the same time I'm not able to call the `loadCountryDataFromCsv(countrySelected, indicatorSelected)` function with the new values.

Comment: Remove the `form` tag and the page won't reload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add an id to your form (say "form1"). then remove the submit.onchange =function and do the following

```js
$('formid').on('submit',function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var minCnt = document.getElementById('minCnt').value;
  var maxCnt = document.getElementById('maxCnt').value;
  range[0] = minCnt; range[1] = maxCnt;
  var countrySelected = document.getElementById('country-select').value;
  var indicatorSelected = document.getElementById('data-select').value;
  loadCountryDataFromCsv(countrySelected, indicatorSelected);
});
```

Comment: is this jquery? becauseI get "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined"

Comment: you will need jquery
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

If you dont want to use jquery, i ll edit the code

Comment: have you ever checked the console of your browser?
The function : 
loadCountryDataFromCsv(countrySelected, indicatorSelected);
is causing your page to refresh

else place the loadCountryDataFromCsv(countrySelected, indicatorSelected) definition outside the function drawChart()

you cant get a function that is not globally defined from updateRange()